# Java serialVersionUid and contained classes

Tags: java, serialization

Consider the below code:

```
class TestSUid implements Serializable {

    private static final Long serialVersionUID =101010101010L; 
    private String title;
    private Error error;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Error getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Error error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}

class Error implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String message;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Now my objective is to serialize the TestSUid class so that I can enable offline caching. 
I am confused on the part if I need to add a serialVersionUID to my Error class as well. 
What if I need to update the error class in future would updating the TestSUid version id be enough?

I have gone through the reference at: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#a6678

But still dont feel entirely confident.

Answer (score 1):

The reference you pointed to, lists compatible and incompatible changes when the class `serialVersionUID` is the same. So if you want to make any compatible change in the future (e.g. add a field to the class) and still be able to deserialize the old data, you should also add the `serialVersionUID` to the class that will change (in this case, also to the `Error` class). Additionally:

1. As per [Serializable javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) you should use the primitive type `long` instead of a class `Long`.
2. If you update the `TestSUid` version id, you will no longer be able to read the serialized data of an older version. You will get an exception: `java.io.InvalidClassException: TestSUid; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = <old_version>, local class serialVersionUID = <new_version>`.
3. If you don't update the `TestSUid` version id and add an additional field to the Error class, the computed (if not declared) `serialVersionUID` will be different than before and you will get the error from pt. 2.